# Шаблоны Проектирования

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Вопрос в правильности использования Шаблонов и построении класса.

В моделе фабрики содержатся методы по созданию функциональных объектов:

- UploadControl - Загрузка файлов
- FileControl - Операции над файлами
- DataBase - Операции с базой данных

И методы для ведения лога внутри этих объектов

- UseObserver - Использование стандартного наблюдателя
- AddObserver - Добавление нового наблюдателя
- RemoveObserver - Удаление наблюдателя
- GetObserver получение наблюдателя

Суть вопроса:
Правильно ли я использую Шаблон фабрики и Наблюдателя?
Как сделать лучше?
Смогу ли я после выполнения функции следующего вида:

```
Module::Upload($_FILES)->Load()
```

Получить из наблюдателя лог ошибок и проделанной работы в функции?

Ниже код фабрики:

```
class ModuleUploadControl{

    protected static $Observer = [];

    public static function Upload($file){
        return new UploadControl($file,self::$Observer);
    }

    public static function Module($nameModule){
        return new FileControl($nameModule,self::$Observer);
    }

    public static function DB($nameModule){
        return new DataBase($nameModule);
    }

    public static function UseObserver(){
        self::$Observer['Log'] = new ObserverLog();
    }

    public static function AddObserver($NameObserver,$Observer){
        self::$Observer[$NameObserver] = $Observer;
    }

    public static function RemoveObserver($NameObserver){
        if (array_key_exists($NameObserver, self::$Observer)) {
            unset(self::$Observer[$NameObserver]);
        }
    }

    public static function GetObserver($NameObserver){
        return isset(self::$Observer[$NameObserver]) ? self::$Observer[$NameObserver] : null;
    }

    public static function GetAllObserver(){
        return self::$Observer;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При проектировании какой либо системы, помимо комбинирования шаблонов проектирования вы должны руководствоваться принципами [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29). Если этого не сделать, то хорошее приложение вам создать не удастся.

Давайте попробуем привести ваш код к человеческому виду, используя эти принципы.

В первую очередь, вам стоит избавится от статических методов и свойств. Помните, каждое такое свойство - это аналог глобальной переменной. Всё состояние объектов должно хранится в свойствах экземпляра класса, иначе вы очень скоро придете к проблемам с масштабируемостью, тестированием и взаимозаменяемостью модулей.

Далее, вам стоит задуматься о передаче всех зависимостей классу в явном виде. Например, вы создаете объект базы данных в некоторой фабрике объектов.

```
public static function DB($nameModule){
    return new DataBase($nameModule);
}
```

Очевидно, что это вовсе не задача фабрики. Весь смысл жизни фабрики должен сводится к созданию продуктов. Все остальное следует вынести куда-то еще.

Далее, вам стоит сократить API для подключения наблюдателей. Хорошим вариантом может быть интерфейс [`SplSubject`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.splsubject.php), либо производной от него. От метода `UseObserver` стоит отказаться.

В классической реализации Наблюдателя, субъекту передается только наблюдатель, без имени. На самом деле, имя является избыточным, поскольку все наблюдатели должны реализовывать один и тот же интерфейс, и субъект не должен знать о деталях их реализации.

Теперь поговорим собственно о логировании. В ряде случаев, экземпляр логера передается объектам в явном виде. Так происходит, например, в Symfony. Я бы рекомендовал вам использовать логер напрямую, вместо заворачивания его в один из наблюдателей. Да, это создаст еще одну явную зависимость у класса, но позволит не реализовывать лишний раз шаблон "Наблюдатель". Кроме того, это позволит упростить ваш код. Если вдруг класс `UploadControl` создает еще какую-то сущность и этой сущности нужен функционал логирования, то у вас начнутся проблемы. `UploadControl` ничего не знает о логере. Все что он может - передать наблюдатель, связанный с логированием. Это мягко говоря костыль. Поэтому, вам на самом деле не нужен шаблон Наблюдатель в данном конкретном случае. Совсем.

Кстати, существует даже унифицированный интерфейс для логгера, определенный в [PSR-3](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/).

Ну и небольшое замечание от перфекциониста напоследок: вам стоит унифицировать имена используемых методов. Если вы используете `GetObserver`, то и вместо `Module` стоит использовать `getModule`. Это упростит жизнь тому, кто будет поддерживать ваш код. Ну и `UseObservet` (обратите внимание на `t` на конце) это вообще жесть.

А еще стоит обратить внимание на популярный стиль именования, описанный в [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) и [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

---

Итак, как может выглядеть код, с учетом замечаний выше:

```
class ModuleUploadControl
{
    protected $moduleName;
    protected $logger;
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($module_name, $db, $logger = null)
    {
        $this->moduleName = $module_name;

        $this->logger = ($logger !== null)
            ? $logger
            // Этот логер не делает ничего. Он просто игнорирует все переданные
            // в него сообщения. А нужен он, чтобы унифицировать
            // поведение фабрики и создаваемых объектов.
            : new DummyLogger();
    }

    public function getUpload($file)
    {
        return new UploadControl($file, $this->logger);
    }

    public function getModule()
    {
        return new FileControl($this->moduleName, $this->logger);
    }

    public function getDatabase()
    {
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

А вот и пример использования:

```
// Подготавливаем зависимости.
$logger = new Logger(/* ... */);
$db = new DataBase(/* ... */);

// Выполняем действия.
$module = new ModuleUploadControl('a_name', $db, $logger);
$module->getUpload($_FILES)->load();

// А лог сохранен в экземпляре $logger.
```

Как-то так.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду разбираться.

Comment: DataBase это не конект к базе и даже не мой класс его я подключил туда для удобства с его помощью проводятся необходимые операции и т.д

Comment: @Shadow33, по-сути это не важно. Если по логике приложения DataBase не является внутренней сущностью `ModuleUploadControl`, то его следует передавать как зависимость.

Comment: хорошо, просто с изучением столкнулся с вопросом когда вообще стоит использовать фабрику или любой из шаблонов. Не будет ли это излишеством просто, как для вывода надписи `Hello world` создавать целую структуру. Посоветуйте может материал для изучения или реальные примеры. Хочу разобраться и использовать в проектах а узнать не у кого так что буду признателен.

Comment: @Shadow33 Весь смысл ООП подхода заключается в снижении локальной сложности разработки ПО. Если приложение маленькое (и его никто никогда не будет развивать), то оверхед из кучи шаблонов явно излишен.

Comment: Благодарю, надеюсь после прочтения нескольких книг  дела станут лучше. Простите за  навязчивость могу ли я получить от вас какие-то контактные данные для советов (не частых) в таком виде как эта статья?

Comment: @Shadow33, частных консультаций я не оказываю. Задавайте вопросы на ru.SO. Думаю, тут есть кому на них ответить ;)

Answer (score 1):

Что-то в `ModuleUploadControl` все намешано: и фабрики, и реализация `Subject` (как части шаблона `Observer`)

Отвечу на вопрос, пожалуй, частично, а именно: как реализовать логгер, используя шаблон `Observer`.

Если есть некоторый объект и требуется получать и, к примеру, логгировать уведомления от этого объекта, то возможна такая реализация логгера:

```
interface ISubject
{
    function attach(\IObserver $observer);
    function detach(\IObserver $observer);
    function notify($event);
}

interface IObserver
{
    function update(\ISubject $subject, $event);
}

class SubjectBase implements \ISubject
{
    private $observers = array();

    function attach(\IObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->observers[] = $observer;
    }

    function detach(\IObserver $observer)
    {
        if ($key = array_search($observer, $this->observers, true)) {
            unset($this->observers[$key]);
        }
    }

    function notify($event)
    {
        foreach ($this->observers as $value) {
            $value->update($this, $event);
        }
    }
}

class Uploader extends SubjectBase
{
    function upload()
    {
        // ...

        $event = 'Hello';

        $this->notify($event); // уведомляем наблюдателей о событии

        // ...
    }
}


class Logger implements \IObserver
{

    function update(\ISubject $subject, $event) {

        // пишем в лог $event
        // ...

        echo $event;
    }
}

$logger = new Logger;

$uploader = new Uploader;
$uploader->attach($logger);

$uploader->upload();
```

В результате будет выведено `'Hello'`.

Вообще, есть отличная книга для начинающих изучать шаблоны проектирования: [Head First Design Patterns](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31079082/). Очень рекомендую.

Comment: огромное спасибо за книгу!